# How to insert time into redshift

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Redshift only support TIMESTAMP format, I want to dump some data that is originally stored in Postgres in time without time zone format. My data looks like this: 15:30:00

When I COPY my data into Redshift, it says Invalid timestamp format or value [YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS], error code 1206.

My current workaround is to create that column in Redshift as CHAR(8)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no other solution that to use the char(8).

Answer (score 1):

Redshift does not support [timezones.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Datetime_types.html)

Workaround would be to parse data to UTC and store time difference in separate column. You will be able to calculate local time by adding/substracting hours to the UTC data.

Comment: just a quick update on this - Redshift DOES now support timestamptz (timestamp with time zone)